# How to scroll collectionViewCell smoothly like news ticker at bottom in swift 4 ios

Tags: uicollectionview, swift4, horizontal-scrolling, smooth-scrolling, marquee

I want to scroll collectionView cells slowly ,Smoothly and automatically like marquee in swift 4.

try to animate with this and works perfectly

```
func startScrolling(){
       let co = collectionView.contentOffset.x            
       let no = co + 1
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.001, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: { [weak self]() -> Void in
               self?.collectionView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: no, y: 0)
               }) { [weak self](finished) -> Void in
                   self?.startScrolling()
                 }
            }
```

But from this not get Index and not clickable also , Need help

Comment: i think when you interact with collectionview, u have to stop animation